# MySql Join using 4 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables and i want to join them and extarct 4 values.

I wrote the followig MySql Query, but it does not work.

```
select `a`.`id`,`a`.`page` xpage,`a`.`action`,
`b`.`header` xheader, `b`.`page_id`,
`c`.`content` xcontent,`b`.`page_id`,
`d`.`footer` xfooter,`d`.`page_id`
join `header` b
on `a`.`id`=`b`.`page_id`
join `content` c
on `a`.`id`=`c`.`page_id` and `a`.`id`=`d`.`page_id`
join `footer` d
on `a`.`id`=`d`.`page_id`
where `a`.`page`='main'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing FROM

Should be like:

```
select `a`.`id`,`a`.`page` xpage,`a`.`action`,
`b`.`header` xheader, `b`.`page_id`,
`c`.`content` xcontent,`b`.`page_id`,
`d`.`footer` xfooter,`d`.`page_id`
from `a`
join `header` b
on `a`.`id`=`b`.`page_id`
join `content` c
on `a`.`id`=`c`.`page_id` and `a`.`id`=`d`.`page_id`
join `footer` d
on `a`.`id`=`d`.`page_id`
where `a`.`page`='main'
```

Comment: stupid me ... SELECT  `a`.`id` ,  `a`.`page` xpage,  `a`.`action` ,  `b`.`header` xheader,  `b`.`page_id` ,  `c`.`content` xcontent,  `b`.`page_id` ,  `d`.`footer` xfooter,  `d`.`page_id` 
FROM  `page` a
JOIN  `header` b ON  `a`.`id` =  `b`.`page_id` 
JOIN  `content` c ON  `a`.`id` =  `c`.`page_id` 
JOIN  `footer` d ON  `a`.`id` =  `d`.`page_id` 
WHERE  `a`.`page` =  'main'
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 2):

You forget the `from` clause here.

```
select `a`.`id`,`a`.`page` xpage,`a`.`action`,
`b`.`header` xheader, `b`.`page_id`,
`c`.`content` xcontent,`b`.`page_id`,
`d`.`footer` xfooter,`d`.`page_id` 
from `a`
join `header` b
on `a`.`id`=`b`.`page_id`
join `content` c
on `a`.`id`=`c`.`page_id` and `a`.`id`=`d`.`page_id`
join `footer` d
on `a`.`id`=`d`.`page_id`
where `a`.`page`='main'
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing a FROM table? Should be

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM page a join header b on a.id=b.page_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `FROM` keyword:

```
select `a`.`id`,`a`.`page` xpage,`a`.`action`,
       `b`.`header` xheader, `b`.`page_id`,
       `c`.`content` xcontent,`b`.`page_id`,
       `d`.`footer` xfooter,`d`.`page_id` 
from `a`
        join `header` b
            on `a`.`id`=`b`.`page_id`
        join `content` c
            on `a`.`id`=`c`.`page_id` and `a`.`id`=`d`.`page_id`
        join `footer` d
            on `a`.`id`=`d`.`page_id`
where `a`.`page`='main'
```